# ScrollView Zooming Issues

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I have a drawing view which is embedded inside a scrollview for zooming purposes. When I try to to zoom the drawing view it zooms but draws a little on the view before zooming. I am using ACEDrawing View library for rendering the drawing view. Any methods by which we can ignore the touches while pinch zooming on the drawing view so that initial little bit drawing can be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass `UIScrollView` and override `touchesShouldBegin` something like this:

```
class CustomScrollView: UIScrollView {

    override func touchesShouldBegin(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?, in view: UIView) -> Bool {
        if event?.allTouches?.count == 2 { return false }
        return super.touchesShouldBegin(touches, with: event, in: view)
    }

}
```

Comment: No it's not working. Still the drawing view draws a little before zooming

Comment: @VaisakhVinod Sorry. I could swear that worked in my test app. In fact it doesn't. But I updated my answer with a different approach. :)